# Is there an R function for finding relative distances between points?

Tags: r, math, geometry, distance, computational-geometry

I have some points distributed on an XY graph like in the picture. Is there a way to recognize the vertex of the polygon (in this case a triangle), and to assign to each point a 3D coordinate value based on the point distances?
Vertex would be (1, 0, 0), (0, 1, 0) and (0, 0, 1), while the other 4 points should be calculated on that reference, for instance the central point should be something like (0.33, 0.4, 0.27).

[image]

Comment: Are you looking for a geometric transformation that maps your three points to (1,0,0), (0,1,0) and (0,0,1)?

Comment: Your explanations are particularly opaque...

Comment: I'm sorry for these poor explanation but I don't know the proper mathematical terminology for this case. It's correct as stated by @Stef, but there's more to just mapping the vertexes of the triangle. I should be able to locate the other four points in the new coordinates.

I see this operation as the transformation of this triangle in a surface that crosses in the vertexes of the triangle the three x y and z axes in (1,0,0), (0,1,0) and (0,0,1). The other points within the triangle would be represented on that surface as x y and z coordinates.

Comment: Simple geometric transformations are a particular case of affine transformations. In the case 2dplane-to-3dspace an affine transformation can be encoded as a dim-3x2 matrix M plus a dim-3 vector T. That is a total of 9 coefficients which you need to find. Every of the three points P=(x0, y0) in your initial triangle is mapped to a point Q=(x', y', z') in space, which translates to the matrix-vector equation M P + T = Q, which is equivalent to 3 equations. Three points + 3 eq per point = 9 eq. Unknowns are the coefficients of M and T. Solve the equations: you will have your transformation.

Comment: Thank you very much, I'll try to solve these equations and get to the coordinates!

Answer (score 0):

I would probably start with the convex hull if you are expecting convex shapes, from there you can check every 3 points and if the angle is below some threshold, delete the middle point from the polygon. Then you can just use a standard algorithm to get the central point of a polygon.

Another solution if an approximation is fine, you might just use the weighted center of all points. Average of the X values and average of the Y values gives you your x/y point. perhaps more effective if you do this with the convex hull points. Though this can be biased if too many points are within a given area. IE: Say there was 100 points near one corner, but only 10 points near the other 2 corners of the triangle. It would be heavily weighted towards that corner with the 100 points.

Not familar with R so that's about the best I can do.